# Can't see W10 shares from W7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, networking

I have a similar problem asked by Chuck about 2 years ago: my configuration is a small home network with two W7, a W10 desktop and a Zyxel NAS (linux)
the situation is

- W10 sees all other three boxes' shares
- both two W7 see each other and the NAS but not the W10 shares
  The message is the same as Chuck's one: the box is seen just the shared folders not.
- Now the strange thing: I've tried to create a network drive on a W7 box using the IP address of the W10 instead of the server name - and it worked! Successfully mapped to the Z: drive.It seems for me that the name resolution is wrong somehow - what can i do?

Comment: using the IP address of the W10 instead of the server name -   ........    Use local HOSTS files to resolve computer names.   c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc

Comment: In Services both `Workstation` and `Server` must be running for names, rather than IP addresses, to work.

Comment: - The hosts file already contains the IP-address-name pair - without solving the issue
- because my local network  is a workgroup I haven't see the workstation/server situation